# restarting app w/o closing it

Tags: android, android-widget, android-2.2-froyo

I have a small little tip calculator app that works pretty well, i am trying to implement a clear button, but with the code i tried it just closes the app, how would i go about starting code over... here is what i tried below..

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            percentage = 0;
            output = 0;
            output1 = "";
             TextView textView = null;

            textView.clearComposingText();

            percentageInp = 0;
            billAmount = 0;

            myEditField.setText("");
            myEditField2.setText("");

            return;
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the textView to null then try to call a method on it so its probably force closing , that closes the app.
Remove the

```
TextView textView = null;
```

To clear the

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText("");
```

This assumes your textview is called textView1. The way you are clearing variables now seems ok and a simple way to do it, since its a tip calculator i assume there aren't many variables to clear, so this manual way will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could essentially pass the former pid to start parameter to an new instance and then killd the old instance when the new instance is loaded. Use `Process.GetCurrentProcess` method to read the old instance pid. Pass the parameter to new instance using `Arguments` property in `ProcessStartInfo`. Then use `Process.GetProcessById` in new instance to get and kill th eold instance when the new instance argument is passed.

Get Process (android):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Comment: I am not sure what this means... sorry i am kinda new

Comment: It means that you basically start a new process from the old process (the old process is passed as a paramter to the new process) and then when the new process kills the old process.

Comment: The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}